# How to get my total to update correctly in vb.net (using textchanged event)

Tags: vb.net

What i have in a text box that is the discount.  The text box talks to the label as you type and updates it accordingly

The problem is that once the discount_rate.text get to 10 or above the discount is off by 5 cents and increases as the number goes up..

Can anybody tell me why?

```
Private Sub discount_rate_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles discount_rate.TextChanged
    Select Case radio
        Case "one"
            If discount_rate.Text = "" Then
                Label17.Text = FormatCurrency(a_total.Text * 50)
                Label19.Text = FormatCurrency(Label17.Text * 0.06)
                a = CDbl(Label17.Text)
                b = CDbl(Label19.Text)
                Label21.Text = FormatCurrency(a + b)
            Else
                discount = discount_rate.text / 100
                discountrate = Label17.Text * discount
                dis_count1.Text = FormatCurrency(discountrate)
                Label17.Text = FormatCurrency((a_total.Text * 50) - discountrate)
                Label19.Text = FormatCurrency(Label17.Text * 0.06)
                a = CDbl(Label17.Text)
                b = CDbl(Label19.Text)
                Label21.Text = FormatCurrency(a + b)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all never use floating point for currency. Double and float are floating point. [If you don't know why that is then you need to read this](http://vladzloteanu.wordpress.com/2010/01/11/why-you-shouldnt-use-float-for-currency-floating-point-issues-explained-for-ruby-and-ror/).

Use Decimal instead.

In your case that would make it something like this.

```
Dim _total as Decimal = Convert.ToDecimal(a_total.Text)
Dim _ihavenoidea = Convert.ToDecimal(Label17.Text)
Label17.Text = FormatCurrency(_total * 50)
Label19.Text = FormatCurrency(ihavenoidea  * 0.06)
a = Convert.ToDecimal(Label17.Text)
b = Convert.ToDecimal(Label19.Text)
Label21.Text = FormatCurrency(a + b)
```

And there is also something to be said for using descriptive variable and control names, the person that will have to maintain your code will thank you for it.

Comment: I figured out that I was doing this wrong
   
 discountrate = Label17.Text * discount 

instead of going through and multipylying the actual variable I was multiplying the new variable